# Why was the fact that the Fc-part of an antibody is crystallizable important enough that the part was named after it? (Fc ="Fragment crystallizable")

Tags: terminology, antibodies, immunology

The typical Y-shape structure of an antibody is often further divided into three parts which correspond to the fragments one obtain when the antibody is digested by the protease papain.

Those are:

- Two "Fab-fragments" where Fab stands for "Fragment antigen binding"
- One "Fc-fragment" where Fc stands for "Fragment crystallizable"

Fab-fragments contain a site that can bind to an antigen so it is intuitive why they are called this way.

I would like to know why the fact that the Fc-fragment is crystallizable was important enough to name the Fc-fragment after this feature rather than just calling it the "Fragment non antigen binding".

[image: Digestion of an antibody by Papain, leaving two Fab portions and on Fc portion for each Ig]

Comment: The answer is almost certainly a historical one - remember that a lot of biology was initially studied and named far before modern methods were available. I think this question would be appropriate over at Biology.SE if a mod doesn't find it particularly connected to medical science.

Comment: Crystallizable indicates that the molecular structure does not vary from molecule to molecule, suggesting that the amino acid sequence of that fragment is the same even for Abs with different specificities.  Thus, it is likely to participate in non-antigen-specific functions of the Ab.